# Should I inform HR about my leaving as CEO is unavailable?

Tags: human-resources, notice-period, resignation

We have a flat hierarchy in our company and I wanted to inform my CEO that I'm leaving the company. Unfortunately he is on a 2-week trip and is not available for the time being.

Should I inform the HR about my leaving as I have a 1 month probation in the new company?

Comment: You need to make sure that the notice period and means clause of your contract are  fulfilled

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

And let them sign, with date, that they received your letter of resignation.

You don´t have a contract with the CEO, you have a contract with the company as legal entity. It is not your problem whom the company chooses to represent itself and who is on vacation. As soon as you letter of resignation is in the sphere of action of that company, they are responsible.

You just have to proof the date. You could also just send it as registered mail and it would suffice if the secretary signed it. But usually it is easiest to do it in person an just have a small paper-receipt with you for them to sign.

Answer (score 2):

At the very least if HR aren't in a position to accept your resignation themselves they should be able to advise you as to who *can*.